# problem with gzip decompression in node.js (incorrect header check)

Tags: python, node.js, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to decrypt a savefile from a game. I already have a working version of this in python, but I cant seem to do it with the equivalet libraries in node.

This is the working python code:

```
import base64, gzip, os, zlib, struct

data = FileOpen(path) #returns file as ASCII
res = Xor(data,11)
fin = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(res.replace('-','+').replace('_','/').encode())[10:],-zlib.MAX_WBITS)
#fin is the decrypted string
```

This is what i tried with node, but zLib just throws 'incorrect header check':

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const xor = require('xor-crypt')
const { base64encode, base64decode } = require('nodejs-base64')

let data = fs.readFileSync(fPath + save).toString('ascii')

let res = xor(data,11)
let gzipd = Buffer.from(base64decode(res.replace('-','+').replace('_','/')).slice(0, -10))
let fin = zlib.inflateSync(gzipd).toString('utf-8')
```

The problem most likely lies in the zlib library, as I cant see why the xor and base64 decryption would be any different. I dont have much experience with decompression.

Here's an example of something im trying to decrypt (in ascii):

```
C?xBJJJJJJJJHTEBqheA::Ndrhlx]lHbYB\\X:DBXJEG92G^]JJJJ
```

This means "Hello, this is a test", and when i decrypt it using the python, it works fine. Can anyone figure out how to decrypt it with node?

Comment: Not sure if it'll fully solve your issue, but Python's `[10:]` is more likely to be the JavaScript's equivalent of `.slice(10)`. (Start at index `10`, up to the end of the array.)

Comment: Same error. I added some more info in the question though, witch might help